# How to use a table like a reference table in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have three tables, one for storing meta information, on for storing sites and one table for refencing the meta information to the sites.

But I can't seem to figure out how to implement it correctly. It would be fairly easy in plain sql, but I want to learn the entity framework core method.

How would you solve this?

**IncludeHubEntry;**

```
public interface IIncludeHubEntry : ISiteBase
{
    string Rel { get; set; }
    int Index { get; set; }
    string Integrity { get; set; }
    string Src { get; set; }
    bool Defer { get; set; }
    bool Async { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
    string Sizes { get; set; }
    bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    CorsCrossoriginTypes Crossorigin { get; set; }
    IncludeEntryTypes EntryType { get; set; }
    int OrderBy { get; set; }
    string Line { get; }
}
```

**IncludeHubIndex.cs (contains the refence between HubEntry and Site):**

```
public interface IIncludeHubIndex : ISiteBase
{
    int IncludeHubId { get; set; }
    int SiteId { get; set; }
}
```

**Site.cs:**

```
public interface ISite : ISiteBase
{
    int AppId { get; set; }
    int CultureCollectionId { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    string WorkName { get; set; }
    CultureCollection Culture { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IncludeHub> Hub { get; set; }
}
```

> To be clear: I want the IEnumerable Hub to contain
>   elements thats referenced in IncludeHubIndex

Comment: wait, we can use interfaces instead classes for model definition? EF can use `IEnumerable` directly instead `ICollection` - how will you add item to the relation? my silly questions aside, you will need to define the relationship two way (ISite has navigation to IIncludeHubIndex and vice versa) using annotation or linq definition on context creation i believe.

Comment: the interfaces are not in use in entity framework core, they're just there to describe the datatables

Comment: If you (think) you know the DB structure then one option is to create the database manually first then use Scaffold-DbContext to reverse engineer it. Once you can see how EF does it then it becomes a lot easier to tweak etc. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/exisitng-db

Comment: this should be doable, shouldnt it? How else do they reccomend to implement similar scenario

Answer (score 0):

Several days late, though the general consensus that I've seen so far on doing this, an having had to do this as well is essentially -

Map all 3 classes to their table, with the middle being along the lines of

```
public interface IIncludeHubIndex : ISiteBase
{
    IIncludeHubEntry IncludeHub { get; set; }
    ISite Site { get; set; }
}
```

and then essentially, the two sides of the join both contain a list is the middle object, its really not ideal and use of Nhibernate as opposed to EF Core avoids this issue, though this seems to be a lacking feature of EF Core currently - though correct me if im wrong.